# how a string object transforms when compared?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log("20">10);  //true 
console.log("20a">"10");  //true 
console.log("20a">10);  //false
```

I want to know why the last one turns false.
And "20a" transforms to what before comparing.

Comment: The details are on page 78 of [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf). I don't have time to trace through it just now though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the MDN page on [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

> For relational abstract comparisons (e.g. <=), the operands are first converted to primitives, then the same Type, before comparison.

```
console.log("20">10);  //true
```

This converts `"20"` to a number `20` and compares it. Since `20` is greater than `10`, it is true.

```
console.log("20a">"10");  //true
```

This compares the two strings. Since `"20a"` is greater (alphabetically) than `"10"`, it is true.

```
console.log("20a">10);  //false
```

This converts `"20a"` to a number. The result is `NaN` (do `+"20a"` to see this in action). `NaN` is not greater than any number, so it returns false.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison algoritm in ECMAScript is described here : http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.8.5

> The comparison x < y, where x and y are values, produces true, false,
>   or undefined (which indicates that at least one operand is NaN). Such
>   a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. Call ToPrimitive(x, hint Number).
> 2. Call ToPrimitive(y, hint Number).
>
> 3.If Type(Result(1)) is String and Type(Result(2)) is String, go to step 16. (Note that this step differs from step 7 in the algorithm for
>   the addition operator + in using and instead of or.)
>
> 4.Call ToNumber(Result(1)).
>
> 5.Call ToNumber(Result(2)).
>
> ...

So in case of `"20a">10`, the javascript engine must apply [ToNumber](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.3) to `"20a"`. The complete algorithm is complex but states that

> If the grammar cannot interpret the string as an expansion of
>   StringNumericLiteral, then the result of ToNumber is NaN.

So you're comparing `NaN` to `10` and any comparison involving `NaN` returns false (or `undefined`, see comments below).

Comment: re your last sentence - doesn't the spec quoted above say that comparing anything to `NaN` is undefined?

Comment: @Alnitak I don't think so. `console.log("20a">10)` gives `false`. But I don't know if it's implementation dependent or specified as IEEE754 makes no distinction between false and undefined.

Comment: _"or undefined (which indicates that at least one operand is `NaN`)"_

Comment: @Alnitak You have a good point. But I don't observe a `undefined` when outputting `"20a">10`...

Comment: it seems like a mismatch between the spec and the implementation.

Comment: Browsers implement slightly different versions of ECMAScript... somebody less lazy than me could check previous ECMAScript versions...

Comment: The one you've quoted is 8 years old.  I checked the current ES5.1 draft and it says the same.

Answer (score 0):

For the last case, Notice that even `"20a" < 10` return false. This highlights the evaluation of `"20a"` at `NaN` during the comparison, as `NaN` compared to any number always returns `false`.